# Clojure: How to count occurrences in a list?

Tags: clojure

I'm still pretty new to clojure, so I apologize if this a bit trivial. Basically, the issue is in the "then" part of the if statement: (if (symbol? (first slist)).

```
;counts the number of occurences of 
(defn count-occurrences [s slist]
 (if (empty? slist)
   0
   (if (symbol? (first slist))
     (if (= (first slist) s)
       (+ 1 (count-occurrences s (rest slist)))
       (+ 0 (count-occurrences s (rest slist))))
     (count-occurrences s (first slist)))))                  ;Problem on this line

(println (count-occurrences 'x '((f x) y (((x z) x)))))
```

Comment: I think using reduce would be a lot more straightforward.

Comment: I think you meant to write `(rest slist)`, not `(first slist)`, on the line with the comment. And note that while this is a good exercise for getting familiar with lists, if you actually wanted to count occurrences in a list you would just implement `count-occurrences` as `(count (filter #(= % s) slist))`.

Comment: @amalloy he's trying to count occurrences in nested lists, it seems. In that case, he needs `(+ (count-occurrences s (first slist)) (count-occurrences s (rest slist)))`. Or he could do what you said with `(flatten slist)`. Might be a legit use of `flatten` in this specific case.

Answer (score 6):

To count elements in a nested list, you could try this function:

```
(defn count-occurrences [s slist]
  (->> slist
       flatten
       (filter #{s})
       count))
```

Test:

```
user> (count-occurrences 'x '((f x) y (((x z) x))))
;; => 3
user> (count-occurrences 'y '((f x) y (((x z) x))))
;; => 1
user> (count-occurrences 'z '((f x) y (((x z) x))))
;; => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As Diego Basch commented, the skeleton of your algorithm ought to be

```
(defn count-occurrences [s slist]
  (+ (count-occurrencies s (first slist))
     (count-occurrencies s (rest slist))))
```

... which has one or two little problems:

- It never terminates.
- It doesn't deal with a symbol.
- It doesn't deal with an empty list.
- `slist` might not be a list, and eventually, through `first` calls,
  won't be.

How do we deal with these problems?

- First, test whether were dealing with a symbol.
- If we aren't, assume it's a list and test whether it's empty.
- If not, apply the skeleton recursion.

... giving us something like this:

```
(defn count-occurrences [s x]
  (if (symbol? x)
    (if (= x s) 1 0)
    (if (empty? x)
      0
      (+ (count-occurrences s (first x))
         (count-occurrences s (rest x))))))
```

... which works:

```
(count-occurrences 'x '((f x) y (((x z) x))))
;3
```

---

This solution has several problems (which you'll come to appreciate) that make [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25616080/1562315) superior in practice. However, if you're trying to get to grips with recursion, this will do nicely.